# Determine the radical of an ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Determine the radical of the ideal $(x^3-y^6,xy-y^3)$ in $C[x,y]$.

I used Nullstellensatz theorem $\sqrt{I}=I(V(I))$.

Factorization gives:
$$x^3-y^6=(x-y^2)(x+(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i) y^2)(x+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i) y^2)$$
$$xy-y^3=y(x-y^2)$$

so $V(I)={(x,y)|x-y^2=0}$

Hence $\sqrt{I}=(x-y^2)$. Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is right.

It is a good idea to factorise your polynomials. The correct factorisation is the following:

$x^3-y^6=(x-y^2)(y^4+xy^2+x^2)$ and $xy-y^3=y(x-y^2)$

Then, a point $(x,y)$ lies in $V(I)$ if and only if one of the following hold:

$x=y^2$ or

$y=0$ and $y^4+xy^2+x^2=0$

As this latter only gives $(0,0)$, already in $V(x-y^2)$, you have indeed $\sqrt{I}=I(V(I))=(x-y^2)$.

Comment: Sorry I edited my post a little bit. Is my new factorization correct, since it is in complex field?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, and gives the same result. You do not need to factorize entirely your polynomial in this case, but you can of course do it if you want.